# Mapping bean from action to a form in struts2

Tags: java, struts2

I use `ModelDriven` to populate param from a form (`value=username, fullname,...`) to a bean in Action (a bean named user).
How can I do the same from action to a form(view that still `value=username, fullname,...` not `user.username, user.fullname, ...`)

- `search.jsp` just get `txtSearch`and submit to view action.
- `ViewAction` get data from Database using `txtSearch` and use UserDTO (property of ViewAction) to hold

  /*
  I don't know how to mapping the property to this view.jsp
  */
- `view.jsp`

  ```
  <s:form action="update" method="post">
    <s:textfield label="Book Id" name="username" value="%{username}"> 
  </s:textfield>
    <s:textfield label="Book Title" name="fullname" value="%{fullname}"> 
  </s:textfield>
    <s:submit label="Update"></s:submit>
  </s:form>
  ```
- with update action above, the result is back to `view.jsp`

Comment: Please add some code to your question, that way more people can help you better.

Comment: thanks for response, I added more explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days waiting, I found 2 way:

```
 1. set refreshModelBeforeResult param of ModelDriven interceptor to true

 2. ActionContext.getContext().getActionInvocation().getStack().push(user);
```